# Unwanted sorting of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have the following code to get the order of elements. But instead of getting an array in the order of the elements, it's alphabetical.

```
function gatherTreeIds( $parent ){
    var GatheredIds = [];
    $parent.children('div.nt_row').each(function(){
        GatheredIds[ this.title ] = 'someValue';
    });
    return GatheredIds;
}

<div id="Wrap">
    <div class="nt_row" title="AAA"></div>        
    <div class="nt_row" title="CCC"></div>
    <div class="nt_row" title="BBB"></div>
</div>
```

[Here is my jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FmyBb/1/) (check console for result). It gives me `['AAA','BBB','CCC']` instead of the desired `['AAA','CCC','BBB']`.

**Important!** This has to get recursive. It is not at this moment to simplify the problem.

Comment: Works for me Chrome v30 `[AAA: "someValue", CCC: "someValue", BBB: "someValue"] (index):29`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: You are talking about `.push()` in the title, but that method does not even appear in your code.

Comment: @CBroe: Correct, my bad. I've been messing with this for a while, I lost track of what is doing what. End of workday here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing the two concepts of arrays and hashes. Arrays have order, while hashes have named keys, you can't have both in a data single structure.

With an array you would use:

```
var GatheredIds = [];
$parent.children('div.nt_row').each(function(){
    GatheredIds.push('someValue');
});
return GatheredIds;
```

If you want to record the item title, you can use an array of hashes:

```
var GatheredIds = [];
$parent.children('div.nt_row').each(function(){
    GatheredIds.push({value: 'someValue', title: this.title);
});
return GatheredIds;
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I used the second method because that allows me to go recursive without trouble

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you store titles as object properties. In your example `GatheredIds` is not array, this is an object.

Objects in JavaScript do not have order (opposite to PHP's map-arrays). If you need to follow the order, you should use arrays instead.

One possible solution:

```
function gatherTreeIds( $parent ){
    return $parent.children('div.nt_row').map(function() {
        return {
            title: this.title,
            value: 'someValue'
        };
    }).get();
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FmyBb/4/

Comment: How is `var GatheredIds = []` creating an object instead of an array?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, Arrays always have index, not property names.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh So what you and VisioN are saying is that `GatheredIds` is an array, but since the code is using syntax like `GatheredIds["AAA"] = 'someValue'`, those are being saved as object properties instead of array elements?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Exactly.

Comment: Your answer is correct and explains it well, I can only mark one as vote, and peter's is more native JS which was more like I want. +1 though

Comment: @Martijn Thanks! What do you mean by *more native JS*? I have just used the full power of jQuery, which made the code shorter and less temporary-variable-oriented.

Comment: Small bits are faster in native js, for example `this.id` vs `$(this).attr('id')`. jQuery is great for some browser incompatibilities and animations and ajax and allot more, but I'd like to get to know/understand how JS works